# add listview to pageindicator fragment

Tags: java, android, list, listview

I want to add a list view to viewpageindicator of sherlok but when I get an error. My code is:
what can i insert a list view to SherlockFragment ?

```
package com.example.vpiabstest;

import java.util.Date;
import java.util.List;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.ListFragment;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.TextView;

 import com.actionbarsherlock.app.SherlockFragment;

public class TestFragment extends SherlockFragment {
private String mContent = "???";
private static final String KEY_TAB_NUM = "key.tab.num";
public static TestFragment newInstance(String text) {
    TestFragment fragment = new TestFragment();

    // Supply num input as an argument.
    Bundle args = new Bundle();
    args.putString(KEY_TAB_NUM, text);
    fragment.setArguments(args);

    return fragment;
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_main, null);
    String text = getString(R.string.tab_page_num) + mContent;

    ((TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.text)).setText(text);

    return view;
}


 **public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
     super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
     setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(),
     android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, list));
 }

 public static final String[] list = new String[]{"France", "London", "Sweden", "Denmark", "Germany", "Finland", "Thailand", "Taiwan", "USA", "Norway", "Denmark (again)", "Lithuania", "Bosnia", "Russia", "Vietnam", "Australia"};**
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    mContent =  getArguments() != null ? getArguments().getString(KEY_TAB_NUM) : "???";
}
}
```

I add the code line but SetListAdapter cause error

```
public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
     super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
     setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(),
     android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, list));
}
```

But this causes the error:

> The method `setListAdapter(ArrayAdapter<String>)` is undefined for the type `TestFragment`

what can I do ?

Comment: The method setListAdapter(ArrayAdapter<String>) is undefined for the type TestFragment

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`TestFragment` should extend `SherlockListFragment`, not `SherlockFragment`, if you wish to use methods like `setListAdapter()`.

Comment: when i use SherlockListFragment other line include error !
what can i doo ?

Comment: what can i insert a list view to SherlockFragment ?

Comment: @user1524393: "when i use SherlockListFragment other line include error ! what can i doo ?" -- fix the error, I guess. "what can i insert a list view to SherlockFragment ?" -- sure, but then you will need to call `setAdapter()` on the `ListView`, not `setListAdapter()` on the `Fragment`.